# Javascript Plugin/Snippet Combiner

Tags: javascript, jquery, generator, builder

I have been searching for something like the download generator at http://jqueryui.com/download.

I have some code snippets and plugins that I would like to be able to chose from on a project by project basis. I don't always need every piece of functionality on a project, so I would like to select individual snippets via a checkbox, and have it them all be downloadable into a single js file.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [*Brunch.io*](http://brunch.io/).  It is a framework agnostic application assembler.  There's no neat gui like jQuery UI, and its certainly not even close to as user friendly.  I haven't quite mastered the art of it, but you can control which scripts are included in a JSON config file that, in turn, downloads the script.  This includes to

Using `brunch --watch server` allows you to deploy a NodeJS server that will continually compile / minify your work as you change it.  Check out a list of [*skeleton's*](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/wiki/Skeletons) other users have made that you can download and try out pretty easily.

If youre looking for a more light-weight thing, i'd recommend [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you may want to do is write simple build scripts using [GearJS](http://gearjs.org/) by Yahoo. It allows you to very simply select a group of files then say concatenate them, and minify them. An example queue would look something like this:

```
var gear= require('gear');

new gear.Queue({registry: new gear.Registry({module: 'gear-lib'})})
  .log('Starting javascript build...')
  .log('Reading js files...')
  .read([
    'js/app.js',
    'js/autoflex.js',
    'js/bootstrap.js',
    'js/jquery.history.js',
    'js/templates.js'])
  .log('concatenating files...')
  .concat()
  .log('minifying...')
  .jsminify()
  .log('saving to js/app.min.js')
  .write('js/app.min.js')
  .run(function(err, results) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(('' + results[0]).length + ' characters');
   });
```

So, this runs with node. You could make a small set of builds using each snippet (app1.build.js->app1.min.js, myapp.build.js->myapp.min.js, etc.) It's not a GUI, but it is a very nice way to perform a set of actions on a group of javascript files.